# Preloading an AVCaptureSession before the view appears (Swift)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I have two `View Controllers` (vc1, vc2). vc2 has a `AVCaptureSession` that loads once the view appears. Instead of having the Camera load from the `AVCaptureSession` when vc2 appears, I would like the `AVCaptureSession` to already be open before the view appears. So if a user is on vc1 the `AVCaptureSession` on vc2 has already started and when the user moves to vc2 the opening of the camera animation can be avoided. Is is possible to do this?

I have attempted to move opening the `AVCaptureSession` to the `viewDidLoad()`, but same result.

Any help is much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

It would be great if you can use delegate function call, in viewDidLoad of VC1 call a method of VC2. You need to initiated VC2 also. So that when you move to VC2, there you have AVCaptureSession.